# How can I submit a Rails form with AJAX but also trigger a jQuery action?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, submit

I'm trying to submit a Rails form with AJAX.

I have some toggle on/off jQuery function that sets some color to green and red, if someone likes or dislikes.

What I'm trying is to have it call my jQuery function to toggle the color and then submit the form with ajax to a rails function with the status of like/dislike submitted.

My form:

```
#wrapper_select.like_select
    =  form_for @paintings, :url => "/paintings/handlelike", :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => {:name => 'form'} do |f|

      = hidden_field_tag :s_id, params[:id]
      = hidden_field_tag :likes, params[:choice]
```

jQuery function:

```
$('.like_select').click(function () {
    if (this.className.match(/like_yes|like_no/)) $(this).toggleClass('like_yes like_no');
    else  $(this).toggleClass('like_yes');

  })
```

How can I call the toggle js function (the function works okay by itself) and submit with ajax the form and then the value if a user likes/dislikes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajaxsubmit function from jquey.form plugin there you can call another function.
here is a link to jquery.form plugin.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_EDIT 2_*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
= javascript_include_tag "jquery.form", "jquery.validate", "attachment_validation"
=  form_for @paintings, :url => "/paintings/handlelike", :method => "post", :remote => true, :html => {:id => "submit_form_id",:onsubmit => "return false;", :name => 'form'} do |f|


  = submit_tag "submit", :class => "ClickClose", :id => "submit_form_btn"
```

your js

```
$("#submit_form_btn").click(function() {
    //call your second function before submitting

          $('#submit_form_id').submit(function() {
            $(this).unbind('submit').ajaxSubmit({
              success: function(data) {
                //do something on success case.
              }
            })
            return false
          });
  });
```

Comment: Thx didn't knew about that plugin, no way to do this native?

Comment: u can also submit form through jquery.submit function but the request will not be an ajax request. While using this plugin you can easily post/upload attachment through ajax request.

Comment: Still this woudent be a non working solution If I where to disable JS in the browser? I can actually not see the bigger picture on how to use this plugin for my purpose actually. what query.submit you mean?

Comment: I am unable to understand why you want to disable javascript in browser? If you disable JS then you will not be able to call a JS function.

Comment: Thx I set to accepted answer and try, not want to disable JS but guess this would not work if JS would not be enabled, so its not degrading gracefully but well can't have it all ;p

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form with Jquery ajax requires extra stuff to handle.

1. form validation
2. collect values and submit it with Jquery POST
3. Processing response and display message

Better to see it. this is a good example i think

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/